# TFS 2015 Release Management - Automatically create release branch in TFVC

Tags: tfs-2015, release-management, tfvc

Is there a task in TFS 2015 Release Management that will automatically create a new Release Branch in TFVC when a release has been created successfully?

I'm trying to use a branch strategy similar to this, where release branches can be used for hotfixes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branch-strategically#how-does-the-team-manage-releases-from-the-version-control-perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a command prompt and use the below tf.exe command. Once all the steps complete the command prompt creates a new branch.

tf branch olditem newitem [/version:versionspec] [/noget] [/lock:(none|checkin|checkout)] [/noprompt] [/silent] [/checkin] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)] [/author:authorname] [/login:username, [password]]

For more information look at below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branch-command

Answer (score 0):

No. Your builds can label TFVC source upon success; in the event that you need to hotfix, you can just create a branch from that label. There's no need to create a servicing branch before you actually need it.